# Rename all functions in a bash script on 'importing' through source command

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal

I was trying to mimic a module system in my bash scripts separate files containing utility functions for string, date, system, etc. which I can import in my main script and do my work. The only thing I miss is, I want to create a namespace style separation on import. So for example, if I import the string-utils file, all functions defined in it should work only when I prepend a `string.` at the beginning of each function name in my main script. I realize I could just name all my functions as for example `string.contains` rather than only `contains` in the utility file itself, but it's not clean and I don't want to do that. I want to somehow declare the function prefix at the time of import. Something like `import * from utils/string as string`. Is there a way I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: `source` is sourcing the code in the file, not importing it, so it is what it is

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano : Yes, that's why I said mimic a module system and used single quotes around the word 'importing' to suggest that I want to source but somehow want to rename all functions on source or just after sourcing them.

Comment: There is no way for a function name to contain a dot or a slash. The best you can do is probably an underscore if you want a separator. (Technically, `@` is permitted too, but it seems cumbersome to use.) The shell really has no mechanism for what you seem to want to do; it's frustrating, but it's the way it is.

Comment: @tripleee You can use dot in function names. Give it a try: `foo.foo () { echo "foo.foo"; }; foo.foo`.

Comment: That's interesting; TIL. I was simply assuming the rules for environment variables applied to function names too, but apparently not!

Comment: _When in posix mode, fname must be a valid shell name and may  not  be  the name of one of the POSIX special builtins.  In default mode, a function name can be any unquoted shell word that does not contain $._

Comment: @tripleee: Technically speaking, you don't have a restriction on the naming of **environment variables**, which in Linux can contain any character except NUL (see the `setenv` function in C), but on the naming of **bash variables**. Since bash unfortunately allows you to assign only to those environment variables which are also bash variables, this restricts the variables you can set from a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

From a practical view point, you are trying to eat your soup using a fork. Bash is not meant for employing name spaces. If you insist in doing something similar, I suggest that the autor of your sourced file cooperates in establishing your idea of a "namespace". For instance, if you your sourced file starts with

```
# This is file function_library.sh
: ${module:=''} # Default: No namespace
fun1() { # Define function without namespace
  ....
}
# Rename the function to be in namespace, based on the answer in
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203583/how-do-i-rename-a-bash-function
eval "$(echo "${module}_fun1()"; declare -f fun1 | tail -n +2)"
```

and so on. When sourcing the file, you do a

```
module=my_name # set namespace
. function_library.sh
```

This is not only cumbersome, it is also odd that the **importer** defines the namespace of a library. A more common concept in namespaces is that the imported module itselt fould define, which namespace it is in, and this would make the awkward renaming unnecessary.

Comment: Is the `$` in `$fun1() {` intentional?

Comment: No. A typo. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the content of the files where your functions are defined. You could do this on the fly with a text processor like `awk`, for example, but this depends on how your functions are declared. Example if they are always declared starting on a separate line with syntax:

```sh
function foo {
...
}
```

Then, you can preprocess the file with:

```sh
$ source <(awk -v prefix="foo." '$1 == "function" {$2 = prefix $2} 1' foo.sh)
```

If your function declarations are less regular you will have to use a more complicated preprocessor. And, more importantly, this is very fragile. If the functions declared in the sourced file are themselves called in the sourced file, or their name used in one way or another (aliases, arrays of function names, whatever), things will get much more complex: you will need to catch all these references and update them too.

Comment: This fails if inside the sourced file, functions call each other, because you would rename the called function, but not the calling one.

Comment: Absolutely, this is very fragile and there are many other possible reasons why it could fail (aliases, for instance). I should have warned about this and I will.

Comment: I think the whole request is already problematic - introducing a module system into a language, which never was intended to have this feature!!!

Comment: Well, this is debatable. Many software libraries are developed (and even some for bash) to add language features that were missing. Error management, sophisticated I/O mechanisms, etc. I agree with you that this particular case is a difficult case but it is however an interesting one and I would not be that surprised that some bash expert suggests a much better solution than my naive attempt.

Comment: It *is* interesting, but in particular with namespaces, it gets tricky and looks like a project on its own. At least I have never encountered a library which is attempting something in this direction. For instance, I tried to present one solution in my own answer to this problem, to demonstrate that this could be possible, but the approach is fragile too and I don't feel that it adds to the maintainability of a real system.

Comment: Just my personal opinion: If someone requests namespaces for a bash project, it means that he has a huge number of _functions_ and wants to avoid name clashes. However, a more realistic bash application would be mostly organized by grouping it into (maybe a huge number of) scripts/programs, and with this, you have the possibility for modularization already via your file system. If someone **needs** namespaces for functions in bash, I would suspect that there is already a flaw in the design of his system.