# Command 'nvm' not found in .bashrc

Tags: bash, nvm

I'm trying to create a function in my .bashrc file to change a symbolic link every time I use "nvm use".

```
change_sl() {
   local version="$1"
   ln -sf "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$version/bin/node" /usr/bin/node
}
nvm() {
   if ["$1" = "use" ]; then
     local version="$2"
     command nvm "$1" "$version"
     change_sl "$(node -v)"
else
     command nvm "$@"
   fi
}
```

but I have this error : Command 'nvm' not found, but there are 13 similar ones.

I'm quite new to bash so if anyone can help me with this that would be great.

Comment: (1) You have a typo in your function, there has to be a space after the `[` command in your `if`. (2) When editing your .bashrc, it will only be loaded if you start a new shell or you explicitly reload it by running `source ~/.bashrc`. Note that the latter case might still produce invalid results due to load order for a new shell and other files adding functions and environment variables too.

Comment: Also, what you want to achieve there is likely not a good idea. With that, you can't (correctly) have multiple different node versions in different shells as the last change overrides the symlink. Instead of relying on hard paths such as `/usr/bin/node`, it's thus generally a better idea to rely on the current `PATH` variable. In a script shebang, you should thus use `!#/usr/bin/env node` instead to use the node executable selected by nvm.

Comment: @HolgerJust Thanks for the answers. The function is called every time I run the nvm command and not just when starting the shell. The context means that this is what we want to do on a vm. The goal is only to test on a version of node in an environment that we cannot easily reproduce locally and revert to the current version when we want. The question concerns the error Command 'nvm' not found.

Comment: In such situation, please paste your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) before asking here in the future. The error in your `if` would have been detected. BTW, the error about `nvm` just means that your [PATH](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-path-environment-variable) is not correct. You can either fix your PATH, or invoke `nvm` by specifying its absolute path explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM itself is a shell function rather than an external executable. As such, you can't invoke `nvm` with `command`. To quote the documentation of the `command` builtin:

> Run `command` with `args` suppressing the normal shell function lookup.  Only builtin commands or commands found in the `PATH` are executed.

As Bash also does not support inheritance or super calls, you first have to create a copy of the original `nvm` function with a different name so that you can call it directly, e.g.

```
eval "$(echo "nvm_orig()"; declare -f nvm | tail -n +2)"

function nvm() {
  nvm_orig "$@"
  if [ "$1" = "use" ]; then
    change_sl "$(node -v)"
  fi
}
```

The technique to create a copy of a function under a different name was shown by [Evan Broder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369211/421705).

Comment: The OP used `command nvm` exactly because he **did not want** to invoke the function named nvm, but the executable. As such, the use of `command` is reasonable.

Comment: @user1934428 There is no separate nvm executable. That's exactly why OP's attempt didn't work. [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) is just a function (or more correctly: a number of functions with a common entry point, aka. [the `nvm` function](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/v0.39.7/nvm.sh#L2833)) which is sourced into the shell. The only way to use nvm is to call the `nvm` function. [There is is no executable `nvm` binary](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#verify-installation).

Comment: While I didn't assume an executable **binary**, I had expected `nvm` to be at least an executable shell script. What bizarre design, which relies on shell functions and therfore is tied to the use in particular shells only! Thanks for pointing this out.